# ACCESS: drop down list based on end date

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to alter a drop down list in an Access form based on a date field.

I have a transaction table:
TransacID - MaterialID - StartDateOfRent - EndDateOfRent

What i would like to do is to prevent users from being able to select MaterialID that has not been returned yet.

Sure it can be done, but i am scraching my head on this one...

Thanks for your help

**EDIT:**
I might not have been clear in my explanations.
Here is some data:

```
| MaterialID: | Car1 | Car2 | Car3 |
```

In my form, the user gets to select any of these cars for rental.
Let say:

```
| Transac1 | Car1 | StartRental = 20181101 | Not Returned        |
|----------|------|------------------------|---------------------|
| Transac2 | Car2 | StartRental = 20181101 | End Date = 20181106 |
```

Then, I would like for the next transactions for the users to be able to pick only `Car2` and `Car3` as they are the only one available.

Many thanks

Matt

Comment: Make a the combobox rowsource a query that only selects MaterialID's where the EndDateOfRent is not null ?

Comment: Hi Minty, i have tried this already, however, this will show nothing in the dropdown list when MaterialID is rented and not returned...

Comment: Ehh … but that was what you asked for. You can't both do and do not display an item.

Comment: Is there an instance where an item _hasn't_ been rented and _hasn't_ been returned?  Stolen or misplaced maybe?

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding your requirement or you aren't making it clear enough for us to grasp. Show us some sample data - what you have and what the result you expect is.

Comment: `MaterialID` is a list of cars stored in another table?

Comment: Yes, MaterialID are stored in another table

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is to show a disabled row in a dropdown box and prevent users from selecting it.  That is not possible in MS Access. All items/Rows are selectable. If you would like to prevent users selecting one of those "disabled" rows, you must either

1. Not show the row at all.
2. Show the row, but when selected, perform a validation and throw error message saying invalid selection or something.

Extending the point 2, you could modify your source query and add a calculated field. I.e. `CanSelect: nz(EndDate,0) < date` 'Change this logic

Once DropDown item has been selected you would then simply

```
if not (canSelect) ThrowErrorMessage; ClearSelection
```

Obviously above is just pseodo code but this should help you to start.